# Why is my macro writing duplicate values when it should be skipping those values?

Tags: excel, vba

At work I'm consolidating several Excel sheets into one, but only want to merge new values into a master sheet. Currently my code does work and will properly add new values, but after a couple minutes it will start adding duplicate values. The code takes the value of a cell from Sheet 2, uses the Find function to see if it exists on Sheet 1, and if not it will add the new data onto Sheet 1. I know this isn't pretty and there's likely a better way to do this (Such as putting the contents of Sheet 2 into an array since it's static), but here's what I've got so far.

Sample table (Note, actual row count on each sheet is about 250k-300k):

| NDC | Daily Average | Drug Name and Strength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 72143025430 | 1.263 | ACCUTANE CAP 40MG |
| 70010016101 | 5.652 | ACETAMINOPHN TAB 500MG |
| 16571010601 | 1.000 | AMITRIPTYLIN TAB 25MG |

```
Sub DoTheThing()

    'This sub is ran from Sheet 2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rowZ As Long, NDC As String, Avg As String, drugName As String, newCounter As Long

    rowZ = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    newCounter = 0

    For i = 2 To rowZ 'Start at 2 to ignore table headers
        NDC = Cells(i, 1)
        Avg = Cells(i, 2)
        drugName = Cells(i, 3)
        If Does_NDC_Exist(NDC, Avg, drugName) Then
            'Debug.Print "NDC does exist"
        Else
            'Debug.Print Cells(i, 3) & NDC & " does not exist"
            newCounter = newCounter + 1
        End If

    Next i

    Debug.Print "Added " & newCounter & " to Compiled list"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function Does_NDC_Exist(NDC As String, Avg As String, drugName As String) As Boolean

    Dim rngAddress As Range
    Set rngAddress = Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(NDC, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
        Does_NDC_Exist = False
        'Call ddFunctions.StoreData(NDC)
        Call AddNewNDC(NDC, Avg, drugName)
    Else
        Does_NDC_Exist = True
    End If

End Function

Function AddNewNDC(NDC As String, Avg As String, drugName As String)

    Dim rowZ As Long
    rowZ = Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Cells(rowZ + 1, 1).Select
    Worksheets(1).Cells(rowZ + 1, 1).Value = NDC
    Worksheets(1).Cells(rowZ + 1, 2).Value = Avg
    Worksheets(1).Cells(rowZ + 1, 3).Value = drugName

End Function
```

I've been working on this for a couple weeks now (I'm pretty new to all of this still, and am slowly learning). When I step into the code and do it slowly/manually review each line, I don't seem to get duplicate values put into Sheet 1. Maybe there's a problem going back and forth so quick between sheets? I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: try commenting out this line in your function - "Cells(rowZ + 1, 1).Select"

Comment: Also try fixing all of your unqualified range/Cells references.  You should always qualify every range reference with a worksheet if you want your code to be robust.

Comment: Whoops, forgot that Select function was even there. Good catch! It was there for debugging when I wrote that bit. 

By qualifying range references, I'm assuming that means declaring and Setting them? If so, it's now planned for tomorrow.

Comment: qualifying here means specifying the worksheet in front of the range, i.e. "NDC = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1)", instead of "NDC = Cells(i, 1)". Unqualified reference means VBA will "look at" the currently active worksheet, which changes in the scope of your code because of that ".Select" line

Comment: If you are new to VBA you should install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  You will learn a lot about how to write robust VBA code by paying attention to the code inspections.  For example, you use of an unqualified range in  'Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count' is a disaster waiting to happen as the active sheet when running code is likely to be different to the active sheet when stepping through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fits better in a single Sub I think.  When searching for an exact value, `Match` is typically faster than `Find`.

FYI you're using `NDC As String`, so you should make sure all of the values in Column A where you're trying to find a match are stored as Text, not as Numbers.

```vb
Sub DoTheThing()

    Dim NDC As String, Avg As String, drugName As String, newCounter As Long
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, i As Long, m
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source") 'for example
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    For i = 2 To wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Start at 2 to ignore table headers
        NDC = wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Avg = wsSrc.Cells(i, 2).Value
        drugName = wsSrc.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        m = Application.Match(NDC, wsDest.Columns(1), 0) 'any match ?
        If IsError(m) Then                               'no match? : use next empty row
            With wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .NumberFormat = "@" 'text
                .Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(NDC, Avg, drugName) 'add values
            End With
            newCounter = newCounter + 1
        End If
        
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Added " & newCounter & " to Compiled list"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this code tomorrow, thanks! If Match is faster than Find, then it's definitely an improvement. I've verified Column A on all sheets is set as Text. This is important so we keep leading 0's, plus some values may have letters in them.

Comment: Next day update, this works!! Thank you so so much for helping with this. You make it seem so easy :)

Comment: Good to hear it's working out